# Reading too many rows using WCF 

Tags: c#, performance

Best way to manage user requests for reading too many rows from a table in database by using a WCF service call

I mean what is performance tips what is the best way?

Comment: Not clear at all - what do you mean? Please elaborate, show some code, explain a bit more! Your WCF service reads too many rows from the database? Well, then just don't do that! Stop at 100 or so (`SELECT TOP 100 ......`) - or what are you looking for??

Comment: ok after reading just 100 record what is should do to show rest of the records

Comment: Show the user that there are more rows - give an opportunity to call your service again, to say: read the next 100 rows and show those. It's called "paging a result set".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would implement paging via the service and pull the data across the wire page by page as required.

A pointer in the right direction:

```
//service interface
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    List<string> DoWork(int page, int pageSize, out int totalRecords);
}

//service implementation
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public List<string> DoWork(int page, int pageSize, out int totalRecords)
    {
        var l = new List<string>();
        totalRecords = l.Count();
        return l.Skip((page - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToList();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take an approach like RavenDb does and automatically limit the size of the results returned. If the user requires more data then the limited, then just use a pager control.